# Transaction log backup size change

Tags: sql-server, backup, transaction-log

We are running six transaction log backups every day on our SQL Server with three hours gap for each succeeding pair. I have noticed the 'data size change' column of the transaction log backups on the server to show 630%, -21%, 0%, 2%, 3%, and -83%. I don't know what these values mean. Sometimes these go up to 1854%. Can anyone tell me what these values mean, and if we should be worried about them?

Comment: Transaction logs for *what* exactly? I'm assuming SQL Server, but clarification would be nice.

Comment: Yes that's right. Transaction Logs for a SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking around, it's hard to find good info on this, so what I'm giving you is a best guess based on what I can research.  I would say that the data size change is the change in data since the last backup.  You can see the larger percentages after a reindexing of the database (among other things), as all of those are captured as transactions in the log.  Subsequent backups would show a reduction in the amount backup up as the transactions stabilized, hence the negative percentages.  I don't think this is anything to be worried about.  I'll give you some links on what I'm basing this off of.

[Log-Shipping and DB FULL backup in-parallel increases size of sub-sequent trn log file size after the backup](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldisasterrecovery/thread/03dccd15-9a46-4d75-8da0-e108b1d72fbd/)

[How do I reduce transaction log backup size after a full backup?](https://serverfault.com/questions/12793/how-do-i-reduce-transaction-log-backup-size-after-a-full-backup)

[BACKUP (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx)

[A transaction log grows unexpectedly or becomes full on a computer that is running SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317375)

Comment: Thanks! Yes that makes a lot of sense. I have noticed that most of the transaction log backups that started after (not exactly on the time) the Full backup finished have huge data size changes. Thanks a lot - couldn't vote you up yet as I'm new here.